# How to add Close Button in Listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Textbox to add cities name to Listbox along with cities name i want to add close button, so i can remove cities names from listbox easily.
below image is for better understand
[image]

HTML

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtcity" runat="Server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnAddcity" runat="server" Text="Add" />
<asp:ListBox ID="listBoxcity" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
<span id="spcity"></span>
```

JQuery

```
$("#btnAddcity").click(function () {
  var txt = $("#txtcity").val();
  $('[id$=listBoxcity]').show();
  var alreadyExist = false;
  $('[id$=listBoxcity] option').each(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == txt) {
    $("#spcity").text('City alread exists');
     alreadyExist = true;
     return;
  }
});
if (!alreadyExist) {
  $('[id$=listBoxcity]').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', txt).text(txt));
 }
});
```

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi : i Added my JQuey Code

Comment: I can't help if you don't provide a fiddle. I need to see all the functionality that you did in a fiddle!

Comment: ok give me some time

Comment: @Sri You can't add delete button in `option`. You need to use custom listbox to do this work.

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi : this is Fiddle link https://fiddle.jshell.net/tz0f5wdL/1/

Comment: @Mohammad : is their any example how to work with custom listbox

Comment: @Sri Do you need to select any item of listbox?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes i want to select

Answer (score 1):

I removed option select, cus you cannot add delete button on option. Just take a look if you were trying to do this:

```js
$("#btnAddcity").click(function () {
  var txt = $("#txtcity").val();
  $('[id$=listBoxcity]').show();
  var alreadyExist = false;
  $('[id$=listBoxcity] option').each(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == txt) {
    $("#spcity").text('City alread exists');
     alreadyExist = true;
     return;
  }
});
if (!alreadyExist) {
  $('[id$=listBoxcity]').append($('<span></span>').attr('value', txt).text(txt));
   $('[id$=listBoxcity]').append($('<a href="#" class="delete">x</a><br>'));
 }
});

$(document).on('click', 'a.delete', function(event){ 
    $(this).prev('span').remove();
    $(this).next('br').remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
a.delete {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #82854C;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input id='txtcity' type="text" /></td>
  <td><input id='btnAddcity' type='button' value='Add' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- <select id='listBoxcity' multiple="multiple" style='width:300px; height:100px;'>

</select> -->
<div id='listBoxcity' multiple="multiple" style='width:300px; height:100px;'>
  
</div>
  <span id='spcity'></span>
```

Comment: Sorry, cus I thought you were looking just for the button, not his functionality. I edited my snippet. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is work for me :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnAddcity").click(function () {
  var txt = $("#txtcity").val();
  $('[id$=listBoxcity]').show();
  var alreadyExist = false;
  $('[id$=listBoxcity] option').each(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == txt) {
    $("#spcity").text('City alread exists');
     alreadyExist = true;
     return;
  }
});
var count = 0;
if (!alreadyExist) {
count++;
  $('[id$=listBoxcity]').append($('<span></span>').attr('value', txt).text(txt));
   $('[id$=listBoxcity]').append($('<div class="delete">x</div><br>'));
 }

 $('.delete').on('click',function(e){
    console.log($(this).closest('span'));
   $(this).next('br').remove();
   $(this).prev('span').remove();
   $(this).remove(); 
  });
});
```

});